# How shall I omit last empty string from list data?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `.csv` file. it has multiple column data like

```
fruit,color,shape,size,price,quantity,
apple,red,,small,,,
orange,orange,,,,,
```

now I want to create a string with above information like

1. apple,red,,small
2. orange,orange

my code is

```
for line in rf:
    data = line.strip().split(",")
```

this is giving me

```
data = ["apple","red","","small","",""]
```

How shall I omit last empty string from list data

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rstrip()` to remove the specified char from the end of the string, could be usefull to remove the comma

```
for line in rf:
    data = line.rstrip("\n,").split(",")
```

Comment: Thank you It is doing what I wanted to do it :)